# processing animation in loop

Tags: animation, processing

so its my first day using processing and i need a bit of help to start with this is my code, im doing the selection sort:

```java
int[] numbers; // Declare array
int currentmin;
int exchange=0;
void setup() {
  frameRate(0.1);
  size(500,500);



numbers = new int[10]; // Create array with 10 cells
   background(105);
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { // random numbers from 1 to 100
     int r = int(random(1,100));  // create  random numbers

  for (int j=0; j<numbers.length; j++) { //make sure not duplications
      if(numbers[j]==r)
        {r=r+1;}
  }
   numbers[i]=r; //fill array with random numbers
  println(r);   
}
 fill(255,0,0);
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { //draw rectangles
  rect(i*40+10,400 ,35, -numbers[i]);

} 
 for (int j=0; j < numbers.length; j++){ //set pivot number


     currentmin=numbers[j];
 for (int i=j+1; i < numbers.length; i++){  //find lowest number in array

   if (numbers[i] < currentmin) {
        currentmin = numbers[i];
    }
 }
  for ( int i=j; i<numbers.length;i++){ //swap pivot with lowest number
    if ( numbers[i]==currentmin){
    exchange=numbers[j];
    numbers[j]=numbers[i];
    numbers[i]=exchange;
  //here
    } 
   }
 }

}

void draw() { 

   background(105);
for (int z = 0; z < numbers.length; z++) {
  rect(z*40+10,400 ,35, -numbers[z]);

    }
}
```

as you can see where i have the comment here im trying to make the thing animated and to see the rectangles change place on each iteration in the first loop, but its not working... any help ? i tried calling draw(); hopelessly but it didnt work... anyway i can get a help ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly a trivial animation to execute. You should really start with something simpler.

But to answer your question, you wouldn't put your animation inside a `for` loop. Instead, you need to make it so the `draw()` function draws a single frame of the animation. Processing automatically calls the `draw()` function 60 times per second, so by changing what's drawn each time, you create an animation.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on creating animations in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation).

Comment: so i understand that their is no simple edit that can fix my code, i need to change the concept and the way im working ?

Comment: @Rida Pretty much. Basically instead of doing the algorithm inside a `for` loop, you'd need to treat each call to `draw()` as a frame. You could do this using sketch-level variables that you update over time. Basically recreate what the `for` loops are doing, but in the `draw()` function.

Comment: god its not working :/ can u write it for me so i can understand it ?

Comment: @Rida That is absolutely not how this works. Please read the tutorial I posted. Get something simpler working first. Slowly work your way towards your goal. If you have follow-up questions, please post an updated [mcve] in a new question post, and we'll go from there. Good luck.